# Conky displays a "u" in my nvidia section and fan speed for my GPU is not working

Tags: nvidia, conky

My conky window displays a "u" to the levt of my Nvidia section, and the fan speed is nonexistent. my .conkyrc file is here: 
https://pastebin.com/mrqvuPP4, 
[Screenshot of my conky window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T57kf.png)
I am on Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop, with GNOME as my DE

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 3):

On line 201 there is a 'u' character in the line. After ${font StyleBats:size=20}

```
{color2}${font StyleBats:size=20}u${font}${offset 12}${voffset -12}GPU Temp ${alignr}${execi 60 nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader} °C
```

delete the 'u'.
You might also want to adjust the offset to fix alignment.
Set it to '30' to match the other labels.

As for your fanspeed, that may be controlled differently on you laptop than what the author of the conky theme may have had. The command to get speed for that particular fan may be different. Use `nvidia-smi` in a terminal and see if that gives you the fan speed. That is the command used in the titus conky theme.

---

I did forget to mention the 'nvidia-settings' command. Try that in a terminal to see if it shows you a fan speed.

You may be able to find any fan sensors your system has with the 'lm-sensors' package:

```
sudo apt install lm-sensors
```

then after it is installed. Read up on the command 'sensors-detect' with `man sensors-detect`. After you have read up on it and seen the "WARNINGS" 
then if you decide to try it then run:

```
sudo sensors-detect --auto
```

After the 'sensors-detect' program completes you may view the sensors it has detected with the command:

```
sensors
```

You may get output similar to this:

```
$ sensors
gl520sm-i2c-0-2d
Adapter: SMBus Via Pro adapter at 5000
+5V:         +5.13 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
+3.3V:       +3.31 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
+12V:       +12.03 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
Vcore:       +2.11 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
fan1:          0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 1)
fan2:          0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 1)
temp1:       +35.0 C  (high = -130.0 C, hyst = -130.0 C)
temp2:       +35.0 C  (high = -130.0 C, hyst = -130.0 C)
cpu0_vid:   +2.050 V
beep_enable:disabled
```

That may have a fan speed sensor that you are looking for.
If you find it you can then edit the conky script line 202 current:

```
${color2}${offset 30}Fan Speed ${alignr}${execi 60 nvidia-settings -q [fan:0]/GPUCurrentFanSpeed -t} %
```

with something like this:
${color2}${offset 30}Fan Speed ${alignr}${execi 60 sensors | grep -m 1 'fan1' | awk '{print $2 " " $3} } %

That would be executing the 'sensor' command, piping the output to grep to filter the line containing "fan1", then using the 'awk' command to print only columns 2 and 3 from that line.

Comment: Thank you! i donw know how i mised that U though.

Comment: You are welcome. The eyes tend to blend it all together after a while.

Comment: yeah, i have a bit of a problem with stuff like that. The fan speed thing is definitely an interesting challnge.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a possible solution to your fan speed.

Comment: i probably should've mentioned that i'm on a laptop, i think i may have miscommunicated where the fans are. they are the system fans.

Comment: I knew that by the type of graphics chip in the photo you posted. The MX150 is for laptops.That is why I suggested maybe try lm-sensors and see if that finds any thing. The fan would be controlled by the motherboards SMBus.